# How to Create Label Doted Underline in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, attributed

I Want to doted underline on label in Swift

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//you can add doted underline string like this in swift 5

```
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello string")
                      string.addAttributes([.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.union(.patternDot).rawValue],
                                    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))
                   
yourLableName.attributedText = string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSAttributedString` for setting underline in swift 5.

```
let string = NSAttributedString(string: "Receiver", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.union(.patternDash).rawValue])
label.attributedText = string
```